# How do I execute a java code that resides on the server from angular 2 application?

Tags: java, node.js, angular, shell

I have an angular 2 application that is deployed on a tomcat server by packaging it as maven war file. I am trying to grab user input from a form in angular when a user clicks on submit it should trigger the java code and do some calculation and return the results back to angular. Can i call a shell script to invoke that class somehow? or is it better to send the input from angular to node.js and have node.js call that java function?

Comment: You should look at angular's HttpClient. It could send a request to a JSP or Servlet on your Tomcat. This way, you don't submit the form. You should create a service that will use HttpClient to get the calculation results.

Comment: How would that work using JSP or Servlet @rickz  ?  that is if I have angular front end and RESTful set up with Node.js and express but a user goes and does the input in the browser  clicks on submit the input only needs to invokes a converter one java method for a conversion...Its a simple http POST and GET call but if its possible without having to create a whole new REST call for the java code that'll be helpful

Comment: The angular app runs on the client's machine. Since you already have the RESTful set up with Node.js, that is where the angular app should probably send it's request. Your Node.js and express app can send a request to your Tomcat.  You can use a Servlet in Tomcat to accept the request from Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical solution for this is to make use of what's called a REST request. You would have the Angular 2 application make a http call (probably using the HttpClient from Angular) to a listening controller (which is a java class) which will process and return the response.

You can find a great deal of details on how to go about implementing such a solution starting here: https://spring.io/understanding/REST

Comment: I'm a little confused why you're using node.js along with a Java based back end?

Comment: I understand. its unconventional but that's how I have it set up. I dont have the set up to migrate to Node.js yet..I still have to use Java and for some functionalities from Java